# Consequences of violation of independence assumption in ANOVA test

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, sampling

Can you please explain me what is the consequences of violation of `independence` assumption in ANOVA test?

I couldn't visualize it.

Does Cochran Theorem relates to `independence` assumption ?

Answer (score 0):

The independence assumption allows us to use simple statistical concepts to quantify the evidence for/against the null hypothesis. That is, independence (among the other assumptions) allows us to say that the [errors from the mean are normally distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance#Assumptions_of_ANOVA). Then we can use the Cochran Theorem to quantify the p-value (how extreme the actual data is given the null hypothesis), which we then use to make a decision.

The Cochran Theorem is the workhorse theorem for ANOVA and [requires independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem#Statement), so yes there is a very strong relation.

Comment: If our model violates independence assumption, can we decompose the total variability?

Comment: If there is no independence (i.e. there is some underlying structure to the errors), then there might be a way to extend Cochran's theorem. However, if that were to exist, then it would be on a case-by-case basis.

A more useful approach would be to generalize ANOVA to regression. A lot of work has been done on making regression work with messy error (residual) structures.